# How to use ROS Melodic with Python 3?

Tags: ubuntu, python

How can we work ROS Melodic with Python3? I have already installed ROS Melodic into my Ubuntu 18.04. It already using Python 2.7. But I need to use it with Python 3.6. I'm trying to have a new version because 2.7 version will expire on the next Year January. So is there any way to work ROS with Python without any errors. I have tried several methods but it didn't work for me. I need to install it in the system, not the virtual environments.

If there is any reliable way to work ROS with Anaconda workspace also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a way to build ROS Melodic for Python 3](https://gist.github.com/drmaj/20b365ddd3c4d69e37c79b01ca17587a) but you are going to have quite some problems using some of the packages such as [`cv_bridge`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=cv_bridge&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).

I would recommend going for [ROS Noetic](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic) if you can since it should allow you to work with Python 3 natively.